# React Native Navigation Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I have this problem with react native, react navigation, even with this error the navigation flow is still working.

Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ key: string; params?: undefined; merge?: boolean | undefined; } | { name: never; key?: string | undefined; params: never; merge?: boolean | undefined; }'.ts(2345)

```
export function LoginContainer() {
    const navigation = useNavigation()
    async function handleSignInEmail() {
        navigation.navigate('SingInEmail')
    }

    return (
        <Container>
                <Image source={Logo} />
                <Title>Você está entrando com uma conta de Cliente.</Title>
                <LoginButton
                    title="Entrar com Google"
                    type="google"
                />
                <LoginButton
                    title="Entrar com Facebook"
                    type="facebook"
                />
                <Divisor/>
                <Links
                    title="Entrar com Email"
                    onPress={handleSignInEmail}
                />
                <Links
                    title="Cadastrar-se"
                />
        </Container>
    )
}
```

The error occurs in `navigation.navigate('SingInEmail')`

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "smart-delivery",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "start": "react-native start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/josefin-sans": "^0.2.0",
    "@expo-google-fonts/ubuntu": "^0.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
    "expo": "~43.0.2",
    "expo-app-loading": "~1.2.1",
    "expo-font": "~10.0.3",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.13.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.1.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.10.13",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-responsive-fontsize": "^0.5.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.8.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.64.12",
    "@types/styled-components-react-native": "^5.1.3",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I believe the error is in the typescript, I'm using this template.

My routes are all centered in an index.tsx, here it is.

```
const { Navigator, Screen } = createNativeStackNavigator();

export function Routes() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Navigator
                screenOptions={{
                    headerShown: false
                }}
            >
                <Screen
                    name="AccessType"
                    component={AccessType}
                />
                <Screen
                    name="SignIn"
                    component={SignIn}
                />
            </Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
```

Comment: I don't see any **SignInEmail** screen, maybe you can replace it with **SignIn**

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your problem is that you're trying to navigate to a route which is not in the router/navigation container.

When calling `navigation.navigate('SingInEmail')`, your component is `SingInEmail`, which is not in a screen.

I suppose you meant to write `navigation.navigate('SignIn')` which is a Screen and so, the navigate returns to the component `SignIn`.

Comment: He mentioned that the flow of navigation is still working correctly, the problem here is with types. I'm also having the same problem as the linter/intellisense is telling me that a string is not assignable as a parameter to `navigation.navigate`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are trying to navigate to "SignInEmail" instead of "SignIn"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that when you are using typescript the IntelliSense comes into play and it warns you about the incorrect type usage. You see, the definition of the `navigate` function is defined as follows:

```
navigate<RouteName extends keyof ParamList>(options: {
    key: string;
    params?: ParamList[RouteName];
    merge?: boolean;
} | {
    name: RouteName;
    key?: string;
    params: ParamList[RouteName];
    merge?: boolean;
}): void;
```

It expects an object with two possible forms. The first form inforces you to define an object such as `o = {`key`: 'some key'}`, the other two object keys are optional as specified in the documentation (observe the definition of the `params` and the `merge`).

The second form expects an object defined as `o = {'name': '<route-name>', ...}` and this is the one you are looking for. Although `params` is not optional in this form you don't need to specify it in this case and you'll have to define the `key` in this case (and I have no idea why as it is defined as optional).

In summary, you could use the following function and IntelliSense will be happy.

```
function to(page: string): void {
  let m = {
      name: page,
      key: '',
  }
  navigation.navigate(m);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide type checking for react-navigation . About this you can read [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/#type-checking-the-navigator).

```
type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  SingInEmail: undefined;
};
```

...

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const RootStack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();
```

After this instead of manually annotating these APIs, you can specify a global type for your root navigator which will be used as the default type.

To do this, you can add this snippet somewhere in your codebase:

```
declare global {
  namespace ReactNavigation {
    interface RootParamList extends RootStackParamList {}
  }
}
```